# Double limit question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that

- $(x_{n},y_{n}) \rightarrow (x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$,
- $(x_{n},y_{n}) \in  X \times Y$, and
- $\lim _{y_{n} \rightarrow y} f(x',y_{n}) = \infty$ for all $x' \in X$.

Is it true that there exists an $N>0$ such that $f(x_{n},y_{n}) > 0 $ for all $n \geq N$?
Seems intuitive but I am a bit stuck.

Comment: In its present form the question does not make sense. Are $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ fixed sequences? 'for all x_n'$ in the hypothesis does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the typo I meant for all $x \in A$.

Comment: Makes no sense to write $f(x',y_n)$ with $x'\in A.$

Comment: Sorry for this typo. I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not necessarily true. The function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous in $(0,1)^2$, and for $x_n=y_n=\frac{1}{n}$, we have $f(x_n,y_n)<0$ for $n\geq 2$, while for $x'\in(0,1)$, we have $f(x',y_n)=n+1-\frac{1}{x'^2}\to\infty$.

**Edit:** To have a counterexample with $f$ bounded below, for $(x,y)\in (0,1)^2$, consider the function $$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{c l}\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}-1, & 0<y<x<1 \\ -1, &\text{otherwise}, \end{array}\right.$$ and choose  $x_n=y_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Yes nice example! What happens if $f(x,y)$ is bounded below. That is, $f(x,y) \geq M$ for some $M$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$. Then it might be true?

Comment: No, still this not true, I edited my answer.

Comment: +1. Similar to an idea of mine: Let $X\times Y=\Bbb R^+\times \Bbb R^+$. Let the $(x,y) $ of the Q be $(0,0).$ Let $f(u,v)=-1+(u/v).$ And let $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,1/n).$

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not true. Suppose f(x,y)=-x+ 1/|y-1|. let y=1, yn=1+1/n, xn=2n.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy $x_n \to x \in \mathbb R$.